# Python __getattr__ 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror, getattr

For the class `Thing`, when I call an undefined method such as `.doamethod()`...

```py
class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __getattr__(self, method):
        print('Run method: '+method)

t = Thing()
t.doamethod()
```

...I get this output:

```
Run method: doamethod
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\person\classtest.py", line 9, in <module>
    t.doamethod()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Since the text `Run method: doamethod` was printed I know the contents of `__getattr__` ran (which is good, I want this) but it also raised `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you think will be returned by `__getattr__`? Why? What do you think will be the next step that the code tries to do with that result? Why? Does it make sense to do that? Why? Hint: the error message is telling you the answers to those questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__getattr__` returns the attribute.  Your implementation of `__getattr__` returns `None` -- so when you say `t.doamethod`, the value of that is `None`, and when you try to call it with `()`, you get the `not callable` error.

If you want your attribute to be a callable no-op, you could do:

```
class Thing:
    # note: no need to add an empty __init__ method here
    def __getattr__(self, method):
        def impl(*args, **kwargs):
            return None
        print(f'Run method: {method}')
        return impl

t = Thing()
t.doamethod    # prints "Run method: doamethod"
t.doamethod()  # prints "Run method: doamethod"
```

If you want the attribute to be a callable that prints "Run method" when it's called (rather than when the method is *accessed*), then put that code inside the function that `__getattr__` returns:

```
class Thing:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        def impl(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f'Run method: {attr}({args}, {kwargs})')
        print(f'Get attribute: {attr}')
        return impl

t = Thing()
func = t.foo          # prints "Get attribute: foo"
func()                # prints "Run method: foo((), {})"
func(42, arg2="bar")  # prints "Run method: foo((42,), {'arg2': 'bar'})"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for, I misunderstood how `__getattr__`  worked.